# Java Streams - forEach with pre-Action and post-Action

Tags: java, java-stream

When using `Stream.forEach()`, I was thinking if it is not possible to add a pre-action and post-action to be executed when the stream is not empty. For example, when printing a List, one could prepend something or write something else when the stream is empty.

Now I came up with something like

```
private static <T> void forEach(Stream<T> stream, Consumer<? super T> action,
    Runnable preAction, Runnable postAction, Runnable ifEmpty) {
    AtomicBoolean hasElements = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Consumer<T> preActionConsumer = x -> {
        if (hasElements.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            preAction.run();
        }
    };
    stream.forEach(preActionConsumer.andThen(action));
    if (hasElements.get()) {
        postAction.run();
    } else {
        ifEmpty.run();
    }
}
```

For sequential streams, this should work, should it not?
Is this method correct, is it as "good idea" have such a method or are there any caveats?

This does not work for parallel streams, since the `preAction` might be slower than another thread executing the `action`, but implementing it correctly without resorting to synchronized or other concurrency utils which defeat the purpose of parallel streams will probably be not easy...

edit: adding use-case. Reading searching integers from a file using a regex and writing them to another file. Using this approach, I don't have to create a String in memory and after that write it to some file. (Obviously, for my real task, I am using more complicated regexes.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("foo.txt"));

    Pattern findInts = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    Path barFile = Paths.get("bar.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(barFile , StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        lines.flatMap(x -> findInts.matcher(x).results())
                .forEach(x-> convertCheckedIOException(() ->  {
                            writer.write(x.group(1));
                            writer.newLine();
                        })
                );
    }
}

public static void convertCheckedIOException(Run r) {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

interface Run {
    void run() throws IOException;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, except that `isEmpty` is `true` if the Stream is _not_ empty...

Comment: well true, I guess I will change it then, as the variable name is not the main point of the question

Comment: Now that I played around with it for a bit... If you want to halt the actions until preaction has finished anyway, wouldn't it be easier to just run it outside the stream like postaction? The preActionConsumer would then just be used to check if there were any elements (and could switch its delegate to prevent accessing the boolean everytime).

Comment: @MalteHartwig: Well the goal was to execute the pre-action only if the stream is not empty. Otherwise, it can be run outside the stream as well.

Comment: Decorating `forEach` is definitely going into the wrong direction. There are plenty of other terminal operations perhaps fitting to your particular actual task, e.g. `Collectors.joining` allows to specify a prefix and suffix. If the only operation you can imagine to be appropriate for your actual task is `forEach`, the Stream API might not be the right tool for that particular job.

Comment: I see, I overlooked that. I have added an attempt in an answer below that executes `preAction` only if elements are present. You can try if it works for you.

Comment: @Holger: added use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tool for your job. This task does not benefit from the Stream API.

```
Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("foo.txt"));
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("bar.txt"), CREATE_NEW)) {

    String s = scanner.findWithinHorizon(intPattern, 0);
    if(s == null) {
        // perform empty action
    } else {
        // perform pre action
        do {
            writer.append(s);
            writer.newLine();
        } while( (s=scanner.findWithinHorizon(intPattern, 0)) != null);
        // perform post action
    }
}
```

You could still bring in a Stream operation, e.g.

```
Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("foo.txt"));
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("bar.txt"), CREATE_NEW)) {

    String firstLine = scanner.findWithinHorizon(intPattern, 0);
    if(firstLine == null) {
        // perform empty action
    } else {
        // perform pre action
        Stream.concat(Stream.of(firstLine),
                      scanner.findAll(intPattern).map(MatchResult::group))
            .forEach(line -> convertCheckedIOException(() ->  {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.newLine();
                })
            );
        // perform post action
    }
}
```

but having to deal with the checked `IOException` just complicates the code for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of having a util like this. At first I thought using a second flag that is set/unset by the preaction and halts the action might be enough. But what makes it more complicated is the fact that preAction is put in front of every action call, not just the first one.

I came up with a synchronized solution that enforces the order `pre`, `actions`, `post/empty`. One caveat is that the first batch of parallel threads will have to wait for the first of them to finish as they will run into `synchronized`:

```
private static <T> void forEach(Stream<T> stream, Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable preAction, Runnable postAction, Runnable ifEmpty)
{
    AtomicBoolean hasElements = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    stream.forEach(new Consumer<T>()
    {
        private Consumer<? super T> delegate = new Consumer<T>()
        {
            private Consumer<? super T> delegate2 = new Consumer<T>()
            {
                @Override
                public void accept(T x)
                {
                    System.out.println("check");
                    hasElements.set(true);
                    preAction.run();
                    action.accept(x);
                    delegate2 = action; // rest of first batch won't run preAction anymore
                    delegate = action; // next batches won't even synchronize anymore
                }
            };

            @Override
            public void accept(T x)
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    delegate2.accept(x);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void accept(T x)
        {
            delegate.accept(x);
        }
    });

    if (hasElements.get()) { postAction.run(); } else { ifEmpty.run(); }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Stream<Integer> s = Stream.generate(() -> 1).limit(1000).parallel();
    forEach(s, i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()), () -> System.out.println("pre"),
            () -> System.out.println("post"), () -> System.out.println("empty"));
}

Output:
check
pre
...
many thread IDs
...
post
```

Comment: I would like more clarifications from the OP regarding the actual task, before creating such a complicated solution. E.g., if parallel support is intended, mind that `forEach` won’t run in order whereas `forEachOrdered` makes the synchronization obsolete. So does sequential execution. But if running in different order is not a problem, a `Collector` based solution would be simpler.

Comment: I can see how a collector could handle `postAction` and `empty` in the finisher, but how would it deal with `preAction`? Wouldn't it have to keep similar state as well?

Comment: Perhaps I have to think a bit longer about it, however, the first question is whether it’s really worth thinking that much about it, as said, it’s not clear whether such a solution is appropriate (or needed at all).